# How can I make this match expression more concise?

Tags: f#

Learning F# by writing blackjack.  I have these types:

```
type Suit = 
| Heart = 0
| Spade = 1
| Diamond = 2
| Club = 3

type Card =
| Ace of Suit
| King of Suit
| Queen of Suit
| Jack of Suit
| ValueCard of int * Suit
```

I have this function (ignoring for now that aces can have 2 different values):

```
let NumericValue =
  function | Ace(Suit.Heart) | Ace(Suit.Spade) | Ace(Suit.Diamond) | Ace(Suit.Club) -> 11
         | King(Suit.Heart) | King(Suit.Spade)| King(Suit.Diamond) | King(Suit.Club) | Queen(Suit.Heart) | Queen(Suit.Spade)| Queen(Suit.Diamond) | Queen(Suit.Club) | Jack(Suit.Heart) | Jack(Suit.Spade)| Jack(Suit.Diamond) | Jack(Suit.Club) -> 10
         | ValueCard(num, x) -> num
```

Is there a way I can include a range or something?  Like [Ace(Suit.Heart) .. Ace(Suit.Club)].  Or even better Ace(*)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want a *wildcard pattern*. The spec (§7.4) says:

> The pattern _ is a wildcard pattern and matches any input.

```
let numericValue = function 
| Ace _-> 11
| King _
| Queen _
| Jack _ -> 10
| ValueCard(num, _) -> num
```

Comment: I wish.  Compiler informs me that Ace is a constructor; it can't be used by itself.

Comment: @dudeNumber4 are you sure you put the wildcard after Ace?

Comment: @MatthewMcveigh, crap, that's what I was missing all along!